# How to responsively center cards on the website in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I am building my coding journal website (on day 15 of learning how to code, so for now only doing HTML and CSS).

I am cataloguing each day as a card with a brief description and a screenshot. I want these cards to stack from the top left [(as they do when I use float: left)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Iua.jpg), but also want them to always be centered on the page, no matter the width of the display. I have tried using display: inline-block, but then the cards [populate from the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgExV.jpg), which I don't want.

Edit: I managed to get it [to this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv6B7.jpg) by using flexboxes as you guys suggested. This is a lot closer to what I want! What I want is for the bottom card to align with the left-most of the top cards. How would I achieve that? Right now my CSS looks like this:

```
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 95%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.entry {
    background-color: white;
    width: 360px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    border: 10px black solid;
}
```

.main is the main containcer, .entry is a card

Comment: can you add some codes please

Comment: I just updated with the CSS I use right now

Answer (score 0):

U should try to use flexbox probably will do what u want.
Try this out
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
Check this site https://alligator.io/css/centering-using-flexbox/ or search some quick flexbox guide, I think you can achieve ur desire with flexbox, if it's not working try using some grid.

Comment: I did end up using flexboxes, however I cannot get them to do exactly what I want. Could you look at the screenshot and CSS I edited into the main post?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a container for your cards.

You can center your container with margins, margin auto pushes your content from the side, If you give your content margin left and right auto, it will be centered.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.card {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aperiam temporibus sequi ipsam repudiandae laborum libero corporis in eaque veniam magnam exercitationem vero consequuntur aut nam, doloremque laboriosam accusantium quidem nobis.</div>
    <div class="card">Voluptatum nisi cupiditate eos omnis! Dolores, tenetur incidunt quis reiciendis nemo sequi voluptatum neque illo sint porro debitis labore sunt consectetur aliquam rem quisquam, pariatur doloremque cum iste et nobis!</div>
    <div class="card">Rem, ipsa eaque? Magnam perspiciatis illum incidunt impedit quae tempora labore eligendi dolores iste, consequuntur adipisci perferendis accusantium praesentium possimus voluptatibus assumenda modi ullam libero consectetur accusamus hic facilis excepturi.</div>
    <div class="card">Atque impedit facere ratione rerum quisquam voluptates saepe fugit, molestiae sed dolorem voluptatum placeat non facilis at, ex harum quis magni rem. Corporis, rerum tempore. Saepe harum optio nam temporibus.</div>
    <div class="card">Natus suscipit ea sint, esse quasi obcaecati voluptatem dignissimos cupiditate at a, itaque est optio impedit nemo eaque, aut velit sapiente asperiores quaerat unde! Laboriosam illo temporibus inventore quos dolore.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful, I didn't know about flexboxes!

Answer (score 0):

You can center (**both** *vertical* and *horizontal*) using the following code:

```css
.box-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1"></div>
```

Live example:

https://liveweave.com/L3Axh7